# Connect two location over a distance of 300 meters with LAN cable

Tags: networking, lan

I have an internet connectivity with a speed of 30Mbps. I want to provide internet to another location which is approximately 300 meters away. I have cat 6 cables and another router.
Does anybody know the chance of an ethernet run working over 200 meters of Cat 6 cable? What other equipment should I get in order to solve this issue.?

Comment: You can't do this simply using such a long cable. One of the ways to overcome your problem is using 2 ADSL modems (as transmitter and receiver over telephone cable). You could get fast enough connection.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

An Ethernet cable supports a maximum length of 100 meters.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. Ethernet can run over optical fiber for thousands of meters. Ethernet is a series of layer-1 and layer-2 protocols, and runs on various media. For UTP, it is limited to 100 meters (assuming 90 meters of solid-core horizontal cable, and a total of 10 meters of stranded patch cable). Some ethernet standards are only a few meters, and some will go kilometers.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1344285/502557) for various ethenet standards and the distances.